# How to Create a Personality Quiz?

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I'm not much of a coder but I've come up with this example. I'm trying to design a personality quiz for my WordPress website, and I want the quiz to give a user different answers depending on radio-button options they choose.

For example in the question below if a user clicked option A and pressed submit I want something like 'Welcome' to appear, but if a user clicks option B and presses submit I want something like 'Hello!' to appear. This quiz is an example of the type of things I am aiming to do: [**Quiz-Site**](http://www.answerbuddy.com/thankful-thanksgiving-quiz).

```
<h3>1. How old are you?</h3>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="A" /> A. 1-50.
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="B" /> B. 50-100.
<input class="button" onclick="getResults()" type="submit" value="Submit" />
<input type="reset" value="Clear" />
```

Comment: And where are you stuck?

Comment: I don't know where to go after the "getResults()" function.

Comment: We don't know what is the getResults() function... Provide relevant code

Comment: I don't have code for the getResults function... That's where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will do it.

```
$('input').click(function(){
    if($(this).attr('value') == "A"){
      alert("WELCOME");
    } else {
      alert("HELLO");
    }
});
```

I think that is what you are looking for.
Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/9RPUh/)

Comment: Also, you could add a value called message to each one, and then have message fire off as an alert.

Comment: Here is that method I was talking about in the last comment. http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/9RPUh/1/

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way that the WELCOME could appear as text underneath the question and only appear after the user has clicked the 1-50 radio button and clicked submit?

Comment: You can do that, its not difficult to do at all. Here are your options. You take the value of the checked box, and append text underneath the textbox.. Not to tricky.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/9RPUh/6/ this will work, but you need to point to a source, you can have it appear anywhere, but this should get you started.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help, works great. But how can I stop the alert from appearing so that it's just the text that appears?

Comment: Here I also added functionality for your clear statment to. jsfiddle.net/cornelas/9RPUh/7/

Comment: Thanks! Have you got any ideas how I could do this on a larger scale? For example what if there was 10 questions? How could I make it so that a different answer is given depending on all the radio button choices they make out of all the ten questions put together?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do this would be to have the radio inputs in a form and POST the form to a php script in your theme.
The form would look like this.

```
<form action="getResults.php" method="post">
    <h3>1. How old are you?</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="A" /> A. 1-50.
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="B" /> B. 50-100.

    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Clear" />
</form>
```

Then in getResults.php check for what radio buttons were set and build your output from there:

```
<?php
if ( isset( $_REQUEST['q1'] ) ) {
    if ($_REQUEST['q1'] == 'A'){
        $output .= 'Welcome!';
    }
    else if ($_REQUEST['q1'] == 'B'){
        $output .= 'Hello';
    }
}
echo $output;
?>
```

You would want to include this script on a results page.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hmmm... The code didn't seem to work, after pressing submit the getResults page just showed up as a blank page.

Comment: I changed the PHP code to use request, try that.

Comment: This is the server side way to do it http://stackoverflow.com/a/20892384/227299 showed the jQuery client side way